# Unable to Tessellate shape error on indexing for valid geo shape

Tags: elasticsearch

this geometry is valid according to the postgresql (postgis) `st_isvalid` method
but Elasticsearch throws illegal_argument_exception error on indexing

https://gist.github.com/owexroasia/127c61ee41304fe2d2d0e0015216a780

> {"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse field
>   [ranges.geometry] of type
>   [geo_shape]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to
>   parse field [ranges.geometry] of type
>   [geo_shape]","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Unable
>   to Tessellate shape

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bug in the Lucene's tessellator

Report:
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/unable-to-tessellate-shape-error-on-indexing-es-7-6/220867

PR: https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/pull/1290

Bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-9251